# php getdate() - Hour not correct

Tags: php

I'm using php in an iframe for a counter.  I am using the getdate(); function.  My local time is no 12:16PM and if I use the getdate(); from php to get the local time now, the hour displays as 13.  Should my answer from php getdate() not be 12?

```
$d1=getdate();
$hournew=$d1['hours'];
echo $hournew . " ";
```

Comment: What is the server's local time? Where is it located? If it's in your own country or time zone, maybe the server is erroneously on DST

Comment: As Pekka pointed out - daylight saving

Comment: The server is on my PC and that is where I check the local time.  Ayn other ideas?

Comment: @wilest What is your php timezone setting? Same with your PC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First do a-

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

check if it is your timezone or not.

Surely it is not, then set your timezone at the top-

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

**[Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)** is the list of timezones.